# Processing – Loading random image / Positioning

Tags: image, position, processing

Super new to processing, but as a visual designer, I don't know much programming, so I don't always get the language (pun intended).

I'm trying to figure out how to upload at least 2 images at random that are masked. I've figured out how to do it in the non-random way, but I'm getting stuck when I start to add randomness.

I can email image examples, since I don't have the reputation for posting multiple links / images.

I found a similar problem / solution from this post:

http://forum.processing.org/one/topic/load-random-image-please-help-a-noob.html

but when I start to add a second image, the positioning starts to get out of whack. I've tried a few combinations of 'imageMode(CENTER)' and something like  'image(img2, width/2, height/2)' in a few places, with varying degrees of success.

I'm sure this is gonna be glaringly obvious to someone.

Thanks so much for helping out!

here's where I'm at right now:

```
PImage img1, img2;
PImage imgMask;
PImage bg;

int rand1, rand2, rand3;

void setup() {
  size(1024, 620);
  smooth(4);
  // imageMode(CENTER);

  rand1 = int(random(0, 4));
  takerandomimage("frag_" + nf(rand1, 3) + ".jpg");
  imageMode(CENTER);

  rand2 = int(random(5, 8));
  takerandomimage("frag_" + nf(rand2, 3) + ".jpg");
  imageMode(CENTER);

  noLoop();
}

void takerandomimage(String fn) {
  img1 = loadImage(fn); //LOAD RANDOM IMAGE
  imgMask = loadImage("caps.png");
  img1.mask(imgMask);
  image(img1, 0, 0); //DISPLAY RANDOM IMAGE

  img2 = loadImage(fn); //LOAD RANDOM IMAGE
  imgMask = loadImage("extrudes.png");
  img2.mask(imgMask);
  image(img2, width/2, height/2); //DISPLAY RANDOM IMAGE
}
```

***UPDATE***

```
PImage img1, img2;
PImage imgMask;
PImage bg;

int rand1, rand2;

void setup() {
  size(1024, 620);
  smooth(4);
  bg = loadImage("1781.jpg");
  imageMode(CENTER);

  rand1 = int(random(0, 8));
  takerandomimage("frag_" + nf(rand1, 3) + ".jpg");

  rand2 = int(random(0, 8));
  takerandomimage("frag_" + nf(rand2, 3) + ".jpg");

  noLoop();
}


void takerandomimage(String fn) {
  img1 = loadImage(fn); //LOAD RANDOM IMAGE
  img2 = loadImage(fn); //LOAD RANDOM IMAGE
}


void draw() {
  background(bg);

  imgMask = loadImage("caps.png");
  img1.mask(imgMask);
  image(img1, width/2, height/2, width, height); //DISPLAY RANDOM IMAGE

  imgMask = loadImage("extrudes.png");
  img2.mask(imgMask);
  image(img2, width/2, height/2, width, height); //DISPLAY RANDOM IMAGE
}
```

***UPDATED OUTPUT IMAGE***

https://www.dropbox.com/s/6c7bz86e5hvtn9h/normal_0.png?dl=0

Comment: first and foremost: put draw code in `void draw() { ... }`, don't put it in setup =) Also note that inside `takerandomimage` you're not loading a random image at all, you know exactly what image to load at that point (so the comment goes after your `rand1 = ...` line, not inside `takerandomimage`). Then: it's worth being precise when you're drawing images. `img(img1, 0, 0, width, height)` is a good start when you're new to programming, because it tells you the rectangle it'll take up. Apply that to img2, too, for explicit positioning control

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "out of whack"? I'm not sure how StackOverflow privileges work, but it would really help to see some images of what you're expecting vs what is happening instead.

Comment: @KevinWorkman here's what came out of the un-random test: (https://www.dropbox.com/s/ir08ipa73fwjpfk/normal.png?dl=0), here's the 'out of whack' I was talking about: (https://www.dropbox.com/s/8537vda0m3jnb5j/normal-4.png?dl=0)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans  So I've experimented (what I think is) the draw code around, and I'm still not understanding why things are being drawn twice. The only way I can get the two masked images to line up is to stagger the img code, like  `img(img1, width/2, height/2, width, height)` and  `img(img2, 0, 0, width, height)`. if that makes sense

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans and isnt the `img1 = loadImage(fn);` line loading the random image? it's a different combo of images displayed every time I hit build. that `(String fn)` doesn't seem to be working in `void draw()`

Comment: here's a .zip of the folder with assets if anyone wanted to take a look: https://www.dropbox.com/s/d2thgkwsn2u1hw7/fragment3-2.zip?dl=0

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans okay, I've fixed the positioning and multiple draws problem by only keeping the `img1 = loadImage(fn)` and `img2 = loadImage(fn)` inside the `void takerandomimage(String fn) {}`, but I'm getting the same random image uploading for both images, and I can't understand why.

Comment: The `takerandomimage("frag_" + nf(rand1, 3) + ".jpg");` tries to load a random image. However, inside `takerandomimage` we are not loading anything random at all, we get fixed input, and load that, no questions asked, no randomising. However, at this point I'd say "let's get to something you can debug, first": take out the random and test against two fixed filenames. Can you make that work? Then work back up to randomised images. If not, you have reduced code that you can put in your post, which helps us help you.

Comment: @MattKnudsen don't de this in comments - put your code update in your post after an "update" heading or the like, and then delete these comments (that way everyone else can easily see the update, too, not just the two of us)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans sorry about that, added the update in the original post. So I had already done a version where I used fixed file names to work, where the loadImage part was in the void setup. should I start from there again and work towards use a new random method?

Comment: the updated code shows us something easier to see why it's wrong: your `img` variables are global, so your first call to `takerandomimage(...)` will set them to something, and then -before any draw- you immediately *rebind* them to two different images. In this case only the last `takerandomimage(...)` will do anything, any prior calls become irrelevant because you're overwriting what they did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to rewrite this a little so that you only load img1/img2 once, instead of multiple times before you hit `draw`, and optimise the other PImages a little in the process:

```
PImage img1, img2, caps, extrudes, bg;

void setup() {
  size(1024, 620);
  smooth(4);
  bg = loadImage("1781.jpg");
  caps = loadImage("caps.png");
  extrudes = loadImage("extrudes.png");
  // Load two random images, and mask
  // them according to what we want:
  img1 = loadRandomImage(0, 4);
  img1.mask(caps);
  img2 = loadRandomImage(4, 8);
  img2.mask(extrudes);
  // set some sketch properties and then move on to draw()
  imageMode(CENTER);
  noLoop();
}

// this loads a file "frag_xxx.jpg" where xxx is a padded
// number between [start] and [end]:
PImage loadRandomImage(int start, int end) {
  String filename = "frag_" + nf(int(random(start,end)), 3) + ".jpg";
  return loadImage(filename);
}

// draw actually does almost nothing:
void draw() {
  background(bg);
  int w = width, h = height, w2 = width/2, h2 = height/2;
  image(img1, w2, h2, w, h);
  image(img2, w2, h2, w, h);
}
```

Comment: thanks! wow, yeah, that double `takerandomimage` part makes total sense. I'm getting this error message though: `fragment4.pde:34:0:34:0: The method nf(float, int, int) in the type PApplet is not applicable for the arguments (float, int)`

Comment: oops, forgot the 0 for "nothing behind the decimal"

Comment: tried that, and I'm getting an error about calling on a weird file name: `The file "frag_001.758.jpg" is missing or inaccessible`

Comment: gah, yes I forgot the int cast! updated and verified.

Comment: nice! thanks so much man! now I have to start experimenting on positioning the images behind the masks. should be fun!